# What is the function of General Protection?

Tags: linux, kernel

In linux, when an interrupt or exception occur, if CUrrent Privilege Level (CPL) is lower privilege than Description Privilege Level (DPL).General Protection will be raised!  but what is the function of General Protection Fault in this situation? please help me!

Comment: The words Privilege and Protection are directly related to the words Security and Reliability.

Answer (score 14):

The processor does not permit transfer of execution to an exception or interrupt-handler procedure in a less privileged code segment than the CPL. An attempt to violate this rule results in a **general-protection exception (#GP)**. more on that(http://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~talon/pentium3.pdf)

Inside the kernel each exception is handled by a **specific exception handler**, which usually sends a Unix **signal** to the process that caused the exception.

In our case : the kernel will generate a signal `SIGSEV`.
The exception handler in this case is `general_protection( )` (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/traps.h)

**EDIT** : in this link you can get a great explanation about how the kernel compare `DPL`, `CPL` and `RPL`:

http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/cpu-rings-privilege-and-protection

Another good link:

http://www.logix.cz/michal/doc/i386/chp06-03.htm

Comment: thank, but how to compare CPL and DPL? and where is reality code in kernel source of linux?